# Running Rspecs From Mounted Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a Ruby on Rails monolithic project that incorporates several mounted engines. Each mounted engine (gem) has its own test suite. I want to know if there's a way that when I push code up in the parent project, it runs the rspecs in all of the engines in addition to its own.

Here's what the structure looks like:

```
- Core
  - Engine_1
  - Engine_2
```

`Core` has a `spec/` folder with its own tests relative to its codebase, and each engine has its own `spec/` folder within the gem.

When I deploy code changes from core, and run it through a CI, I want to be able to run a `rspec` command that runs the test from `Core` but also from all its engine parts. Is there a way to accomplish this? I hope it makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Each engine (gem) should run its test suite as part of its *own* deployment process - i.e. you do not publish a new version of the engine (gem) unless the tests pass.

Comment: You don't need to run tests for gems as part of the main application deployment, because these have already been tested. Just like you don't run the test suite for every other gem in your `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord that totally makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up.